# Making a box joint jig

Tags: jig, box-joint

I want to make a box joint jig for my table saw and have the 'squares' if you will, a quarter inch. I found a very simple and nice design for my table saw to do this easily. But it showed that you need to have a dado blade in for it to work. I can not do this and wanted to know if there was a design alternative. Otherwise I do have a router table and that would be fine of course too. But there is also a Problem I see that will be in affect. There is only one track. Not two (I have basic equipment, only 16.5) and I think that would not be stable enough for that accurate cut. What design would be recommended? I want to do table saw but can only have one blade in, unless there is a way to do it with a router table with one track. I will be getting a band saw soon but that would take to long and that can be inaccurate...

Comment: Can you get wobble washers in the US?: They're commonly used over here to give a slightly wider cut from a table saw blade.

Comment: Re. your router table having only one track, I presume it does have two sides that are exactly parallel to it which can be used as registration surfaces also.

Comment: @Graphus Not sure what you are referring to. But if you mean the track and the fence then yes. To help with what your asking here is the router table I bought. This is very slightly different but same look. http://www.ebay.com/itm/Bench-top-Router-Table-with-1-3-4-HP-Router-11-amps-/162200623385?hash=item25c3e91919:g:YU4AAOSwOdpX1yJg

Comment: Not the track and the fence, two of the four edges (the fence is removed or pushed out of the way when doing finger joints/box joints). The tops of router tables are usually exactly rectangular yes? You don't need two *tracks* if you want greater accuracy, you just need two reference surfaces and isn't the track parallel to two of the fours sides? So you can use an edge as you'd use a second track. But never mind that, I see online that there are many single-track box-joint jig — just make a long slide for the track (tight fit) and fix it rigidly to your sled and you'll have enough accuracy.

Comment: I understand what you where talking about now. I can't believe I never thought of using the sides. I think it would be more accurate to use the two sides over the one track. I do not like the track anyway, it is funny. I think I have a good idea how I could make a jig. Thanks!

Comment: Also, router jigs for box joints **do** exist. I don't have the experience to properly cover this, but a google search will reveal a bunch of different designs. For example, this one: http://www.routerworkshop.com/boxjoints.html

Answer (score 2):

It's possible using a relatively complex screw advance box joint jig. It's difficult to explain, but there's a great video demonstrating it [here](https://youtu.be/oCEgajkvVGE).

Basically, you move the workpiece incrementally to make multiple, somewhat precisely spaced cuts for each finger.

Note that you'll want a square cutting table saw blade.

Comment: I like this guy, I watch his videos all the time! Will watch.

Comment: Note there's also a slightly less flexible, but smaller in footprint and simpler, "Ultimate box joint jig". The creators of both get along, and posted [Box joint jig rivalry](https://youtu.be/4AxOWniK7Go) and [Box Joint Jig Showdown!](https://youtu.be/5hQEM3-DKCU) (different takes on the same footage) just a few weeks ago.

Comment: I passed on the ultimate jig because the question was about 1/4 inch joints. If a person wants to make blade width joints, that's a great jig.

Comment: Sure, but like with the SABJJ, the UBJJ can take multiple kerfs for a single finger. You have fewer reasonable resulting sizes from the UBJJ, but 1/4" joints from an 1/8" blade is a very reasonable outcome from either jig (take two kerfs, skip two kerfs, ...).

Answer (score 1):

Box joint jigs generally count on being able to cut the slot in a single pass. If you want a 1/4 inch cut, that means you need a 1/4 inch thick cut, which is why a dado blade is used.

Theoretically there could be a jig which registered off the two sides of the cut and let you take multiple passes with a normal blade, but that would be a rather finicky design, I think.

If you can't use a dado blade for whatever reason, another approach would be a finger-joint jig that runs on your router table, using a quarter inch straight bit to make the cut.

Comment: My table saw is a basic starter one i got some year or two ago. It simply does not handle dado's of any kind.

Comment: Most will, well enough for this task. You may need to buy or make a new insert... As I say, your alternative is a router, invent your own jig, cut by hand, or a mix of these.